# Put two queries to trigger statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I put following queries in trigger (it was created ok) and will they run/execute in following order, first insert then update?

GO

```
CREATE TRIGGER [FieldID]
ON [Field].[AttributeValues]
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
    INSERT INTO [Field].[Field_ElementID] (Path) 
        SELECT DISTINCT Path     
        FROM [Field].[AttributeValues] 
        WHERE Path NOT IN (SELECT Path FROM [Field].[Field_ElementID])

    UPDATE [Field].[AttributeValues] 
    SET PathID = (SELECT Id FROM [Field].[Field_ElementID] 
                  WHERE [Field].[AttributeValues].[Path] = [Field].[Field_ElementID].[Path]) 
    WHERE PathID IS NULL
GO
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: @marc_s that's not true. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a94dab36026e4077379067cf11179f71). It is, however, good practice.

Comment: @Larnu so will my queries work as expected?

Comment: I didn't say that @JoeGreen .

Comment: Honestly, I'm confused, why are you not referencing the `inserted` object. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: @Larnu so my goal is when someone add the row to [AttributeValues] then it needs to run these two queries: Insert row to [Field_ElementID] if it doesn't exist then Update [Field].[AttributeValues] table and set ID (from [Field_ElementID]) for new row

Comment: If you're only therefore dealing with new rows, then why aren't you using the `inserted` object, as I asked before?

Comment: it actually works, these two queries work as expected, first insert then update once new row is added to [Field_ElementID], I need to generate ID for duplicate data in  [Field].[AttributeValues]  so I generate ID first in [Field_ElementID] then update [Field].[AttributeValues]

Answer (score 0):

Personally (if I understand your SQL correctly) I would do this, but your second query seems odd, as it doesn't reference `inserted` at all.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [FieldID]
ON [Field].[AttributeValues]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO FE ([Path])
    SELECT DISTINCT i.[Path]
    FROM inserted i
         LEFT JOIN [Field].[Field_ElementID] FE ON I.[Path] = FE.[Path]
    WHERE FE.ID IS NULL; --Needs correcting, if incorrect

    UPDATE AV
    SET PathID = FE.ID
    FROM [Field].[AttributeValues] --Seems really odd this doesn't reference inserted at all
         JOIN [Field].[Field_ElementID] FE ON AV.[Path] = FE.[Path]
    WHERE AV.PathID IS NULL;

END;
```